# addObjectsFromArray error : how to convert `Array<Character>` to `[AnyObject]`?

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to convert a `String` to `Array`, then count the duplicate values by `NSCountedSet`.

These code get error:

```
    let str = "hello"
    let ar = Array(str.characters)
    let set = NSCountedSet()
    set.addObjectsFromArray(ar)
```

Error:

```
 error: cannot convert value of type 'Array<_Element>' (aka 'Array<Character>') to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'
    set.addObjectsFromArray(ar)
```

I know the reason, so how to convert `Array<Character>` to `[AnyObject]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character it is not convertible to AnyObject. You need to map your Characters into Strings before adding it to your Counted Set:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let stringArray = str.characters.map{String($0)}
let countedSet = NSCountedSet()
countedSet.addObjectsFromArray(stringArray)
```